# Only if statement and no else statement on 1 line

Tags: python, if-statement, one-liner

**Question:**

I know it's possible to just put an if statement on one line but is there a way to do it so that PEP8 doesn't reformat it to be on two lines? I know that you can put it on two lines but that doesn't answer my question about the possibility of putting it on one line.

**Attempts:**

```
if date > p1_max_date: p1_max_date = date
```

The above code works except for the fact that PEP8 reformats it to this:

```
if date > p1_max_date:
            p1_max_date = date
```

I know that I can turn off the auto-format feature on save, but is there a way to achieve the same functionality on one line (only execute the statement if the `if` condition is true without having an `else` statement) without turning off the PEP8 reformat on save feature?

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
p1_max_date = date if date > p1_max_date
```

But this gave me a syntax error:

```
File "<string>", line 1
    p1_max_date = date if date > p1_max_date
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried using the ternary operator but neither of the following attempts work:

```
p1_max_date = date if date > p1_max_date else pass
# this doesn't work and gives me a syntax error
```

```
p1_max_date = date if date > p1_max_date else None
# this doesn't work because I don't want to change the value of the variable if the condition is false
```

Comment: You can try to use `and`:

Comment: Do you want to type up an answer for that? I'm not sure I understand how I would use ```and:``` and where to put it

Comment: Sorry, I have a bad network connection - will provide you with the answer later

Comment: No problem thank you for the contribution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
p1_max_date = date if date > p1_max_date else p1_max_date
```

should do it.
Depending on the data type of `date` and `p1_max_date`, you might also use

```
p1_max_date = max(p1_max_date, date)
```

, which is probably the easier to read solution.

Answer (score 2):

Another one-line approach for this task:

```py
p1_max_date = date > p1_max_date and date or p1_max_date
```

*and* and *or* support lazy evaluation and can be used to return values, [here](https://realpython.com/python-operators-expressions/#logical-operators) you can read more about logical operators and expressions in python.
It is a less readable approach and usually frowned upon but it is a nice trick to know.